# Div id tag not working on tumblr theme

Tags: css, html, tags, tumblr

Sorry, this is probably a "noob" question, but here it goes...
I'm modifying the header to a sidebar on my tumblr theme. I created a new class, but realized I could create an id due to the fact that I was only going to be using it for that one instance. I created a new id:

```
#bigborder {font-size: 13px; height: 25px; padding: 2px; letter-spacing: 2px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #999; background-color: #222;}
```

I placed it where the old div class tag was:

```
<div id="left"><div class="border"><center><a href="/">Page Title</a></center></div>
```

to

```
<div id="left"><div id="bigborder"><center><a href="/">Untitled</a></center></div>
```

and the words reverted to the default for body text.

Here is the entire CSS from the page for reference:

```
    <style type="text/css">

    iframe#ask_form {height: 150px!important;}

    img, img a {border: none;}

    body {font-family: offside; font-size: 7pt !important; color: #e4e4e4; background-color: #222; background-image:url(''); background-attachment: relative; margin-top:15px;}

    a {color: #fff; text-decoration: none !important; -webkit-transition-duration: .3s; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px;}

    #center {width:500px; background-color: transparent; padding:10px; margin: auto; font-size: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px;}

    #right {top: 30px; left:50%; margin-left:268px; position:fixed; width: 150px; text-transform: lowercase; padding: 5px; background-color: ; -webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px; }

    #left {top: 30px; right:50%; margin-right:268px; position:fixed; width: 150px; text-transform: lowercase; padding: 5px; background-color: ; -webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;}

    .desc {padding: 9px; margin-bottom: 7px; font-size: 10px; width: auto;}

    .drop {margin-top: 5px; font-size: 10px;}

    #qtm {margin: 5px; display: inline-block; font-size: 40px; float: left;}

    #qt {margin: 5px; display: inline-block; font-size: 18px; width: 400px;}

    #src {font-size: 10px;}

    .entry {padding: 5px; background-color: #333; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px; -webkit-transition-duration: .1s; -webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px; overflow: hidden;}

    .entry:hover #perma {display: block;}

    .entry a {-webkit-transition-duration: .3s; color: #999;}

    .entry a:hover {color: #fff; texxt-transform: uppercase !important;}

    blockquote {border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style: dashed; border-opacity:.5; border-left-color: #666; padding:0px; padding-left: 5px; margin: 5px;}

    .search {width: 140px; background-color: #dcdcdc; font-size: 10px; border: none; text-align: center; padding: 5px;}

    .header {color: #fff; padding-bottom: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #444; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 25px; font-family: offside; -webkit-transition-duration: .3s; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; }

    h2 {color: #fff; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size:20px;font-family: offside; -webkit-transition-duration: .3s; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: none; }

    .title {
    font-family: offside;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform:none;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .3s; 
    }

    #perma {display: none; margin-top: 5px;}

    .perma {text-align: center; background-color:; padding: 1px; font-size: 10px;}

    .perma_info {margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;}

    .caption {margin-top: 5px; padding: 2px; background-color: font-size: 9pt; color: #e4e4e4;}

    .nav1 {font-size: 20px; margin-top: 5px; padding: 5px;}

    .nav2 {font-size: 20px; text-align: right; padding: 5px; margin-top: -34px;}

    .ask {padding: 5px; z-index: 1000000000; font-size: 30px; font-family: offside;}

    .q {background-color: #444; color: #fff; font-size: 12px;}

    .tri {font-size: 12px; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 3px; color: ; z-index: -1000; margin-left: 15px;}

    .audio {width: 490px; text-align: center; background-color: #e4e4e4;}

    .label {font-weight: bold; margin-right: 15px;}

    blockquote p, ul{ margin:0px; padding:0px; }

    ul, ol, li{list-style:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

    .pages {margin: 5px 0 5px 0; text-align: center; line-height: 20px;}

    .pages a {padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px; background-color: #444; -webkit-transition-duration: .3s; color: #fff;}

    .pages a:hover {background-color: #222; color: #fff;}

    .touch {text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 3px; background-color: #0e49ab; text-align: right; -webkit-transition-duration: .3s; color: #fff; font-size: 8px; letter-spacing: 2px;}

    .touch:hover {background-color: #222; color: #fff;}

    .navi {margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 3px; background-color: #ffffff; -webkit-transition-duration: .3s; color: #777777;}

    .navi:hover {background-color: {color:Link Background Hover}; color: {color:Link Font Hover};}

    .border {font-size: 13px; height: 15px; padding: 2px; letter-spacing: 2px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #999; background-color: #222; margin-bottom: 13px; border: #333 1px solid; -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;}

    .border a {color: #999; -webkit-transition-duration: .3s; width: 500px; }
    .border a:hover (color: #fff;)

    #bigborder {font-size: 13px; height: 25px; padding: 2px; letter-spacing: 2px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #999; background-color: #222;}


    </style>
```

So my question is, how would I go about changing the border size since it does not work with the div id I created. Any errors cited?

Answer (score 0):

On this line there only appears to be one closing `<div>` tag.

```
<div id="left">
  <div id="bigborder">
    <center><a href="/">Untitled</a></center>
  </div>
```

Should there be a closing `</div>` tag for `<div id="left">`?

**EDIT**

I've noticed your original class `.border` has border styles set, but your new ID `#bigborder` does not have any?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, but farther below there is one that closes it after all of the other code (for the bottom of the sidebar).

Comment: ok no problem, please ignore my original answer, but please also see my edit, as another possible reason.

Comment: (Thanks for all of the help so far by the way. Thank you, really!) I went in and copied the code from .border and pasted it into #bigborder to see if that would resolve the issue. It didn't, so I think there may be some small problem with the rest of the HTML. I'll continue my search through the code.